# Trying to check if a code is saved in a text file using python

Tags: python, pickle

I'm making a program that will save items along with their `code`, `price`, and `quantity` with the **pickle** module.

When someone wants to shop they enter a `code`. I'm trying to check the text document to see if that `code` is saved, but it doesn't seem to work and gives me this error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

Can anyone help?

```
stock = readfile()
print("Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the items you want to buy, when you are done type DONE")
while True:
    code = input("Enter GTIN-8 code or DONE ")
    if code == "DONE":
        break
    else:
        amount = int(input("How many would you like? "))

if code in stock:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: error on which line and what is readfile()

Comment: The error is in line 66 which is the line `if code in stock:`

Comment: then stock has to be None, then only you can get this error

Comment: could you share readfile, looks like you are not returning any thing from readfile

Comment: Why are you using pickle? sqlite seems much better-suited to this task.

Comment: @HughBothwell, You are right, I would use sqlite but I was challenged to do it with pickle.

Answer (score 0):

The `stock` variable is being set to `None` by the `readfile` function. The problem is likely in that function (possibly it is not actually opening the file?).

Comment: I have readfile() defined earlier in the program, I did it like this                 `def readfile():
    pickle.load(open("fruit.txt","rb"))`

Comment: @Conner shouldn't readfile be `def readfile(): return pickle.load(open("fruit.txt", "rb"))`?  It looks like it loads the information, but does not return it.  Hence it would return None.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for readlines():

```
def readlines():
    return [line.strip() for line in open('fruit.txt','r').readlines()]
```

Comment: That makes it so there is now no error, however it wont print "Yes" which it should when I enter a code that I know is correct.

Comment: Can you give me a small snippet of fruit.txt and a sample input for the `code = ...` line?

Comment: fruit.txt is pickled so its hard to understand but here you go `€]q (Xi   â‚¬}q (K]q(X   GTX 980qX   500qX   10qeK]q(X   GTX 970qX   250qX` Also a sample input for a GTIN-8 code would be any 8 digit code such as 00000001.

Comment: Okay, in the future it's better to name the file something like `fruit.pickle`, `.txt` is a bit misleading. What does the object that is being pickled look like?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean, im taking inputs like this `data.append(input("Please enter the name of the item "))` if that is what you mean

Comment: I just noticed your `readlines()` does not return anything. Add `return` in front of the `pickle.load...` line and try it.

Comment: I actually changed the readfile() becuase it wasnt working perfectly, it now is `with open("fruit.txt", "rb") as file:`
        `x = pickle.load(file)`
    `return x`

Comment: So the issue was that it was not returning anything, and now the code works as intended?

Comment: No, it still wont print "Yes" at the end, it will only print "No" even if the code is saved.

Comment: Can you try `print(stock)` under the first line and post the output?

Comment: It returned this `{1: ['GTX 980', '500', '10'], 2: ['GTX 970', '250', '4'], 3: ['R9 390', '200', '2'], 69: ['g', '500', '2']}`

Comment: Are these valid codes? Only 2 of them have 8 numeric digits.

Comment: Sorry took a while to reply, they can currently be anything but in the finished program they should be 8 digit codes.

Comment: What you have is a dictionary with the values being the codes split into different items of a list for some reason. If you can get them into just a list of strings like `['12345678','87654321','10293847']` then your code should work now. An alternative method is to not write to pickle but just to a standard .txt, this seems like the obvious solution and unless there's a reason you need to pickle it you should just write each code to a line of fruit.txt.

Comment: I need them split into groups really because I need the codes to relate to an item and also the amount and stock of that item

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of variety, here is an alternative version using `sqlite3`.

*(Note: money is handled as integer cents.)*

```
import sqlite3

DATABASE = 'stock.db'

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def money_str(price, min_width=6):
    return "$ {1:{0:d}d}.{2:02d}".format(min_width - 5, price // 100, price % 100)

def make_stock_table(conn):
    conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stock;")
    conn.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE Stock (
            code     INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            name     TEXT     NOT NULL,
            price    INTEGER  NOT NULL,
            quantity INTEGER  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0)
        );
        """
    )
    conn.commit()

def add_stock_code(conn, code, name, price):
    conn.execute(
        """
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Stock (
            code, name, price
        ) VALUES (
            ?, ?, ?
        );
        """,
        (code, name, price)
    )
    conn.commit()

def add_stock_quantity(conn, code, quantity):
    conn.execute(
        """
        UPDATE Stock
        SET quantity = quantity + ?
        WHERE code = ?
        """,
        (quantity, code)
    )
    conn.commit()

def buy_stock(conn, code, quantity):
    result = conn.execute("SELECT quantity, price FROM Stock WHERE code = ?", (code,)).fetchone()
    if not result:
        raise ValueError('No entry for code {}'.format(code))
    on_hand, price = result
    if on_hand < quantity:
        raise ValueError('Cannot buy {}, only {} on hand'.format(quantity, on_hand))
    conn.execute(
        """
        UPDATE Stock
        SET quantity = quantity - ?
        WHERE code = ?
        """,
        (quantity, code)
    )
    conn.commit()
    return quantity * price

def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)

    # create some test data
    make_stock_table(conn)
    add_stock_code(conn, 2429, "Golden Delicious Apples", 249)
    add_stock_quantity(conn, 2429, 20)
    add_stock_code(conn, 2514, "Macintosh Apples", 179)
    add_stock_quantity(conn, 2514, 35)

    # sell
    while True:
        code = get_int("Enter product GTIN-8 code (or 0 to quit): ")
        if code == 0:
            break
        quantity = get_int("How many would you like? ")
        try:
            cost = buy_stock(conn, code, quantity)
            print("Cost is {}".format(money_str(cost)))
        except ValueError as ve:
            print(ve)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```